Не могу найти dart2native
Не могу найти в папке с SDK Flutter dart2native. Его нет ни по пути
C:\Flutter\bin ни  C:\Flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
Вопрос: где его искать?

С версии 2.15.0, изданной 2021-12-08, он удалён.
Его заменили команды dart compile exe и dart compile aot-snapshot.

А как тогда скомпилировать в динамическую библиотеку? Я пробовала использовать dart compile для этого - оно не работает.
